# Extract similar dates from multiple pandas data-frame

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe, timestamp, extract

My 500 data frames look like this, it is a **day based** data for 2 years.

1. Date       |          Column A   |   Column B
2. 2017-04-04
3. 2017-04-05
4. 2017-04-06
5. 2017-04-07
6. ....
7. 2017-04-02
8. ...
9. 2019-02-01
10. 2019-02-11
11. 2019-02-22
12. 2019-02-27
13. 2019-03-01
14. 2019-04-01
15. 2019-05-01

All the data frames have a similar number of columns, but a different number of rows. All these DataFrames have a few similar timestamps. I want to exact common timestamps from all my data frames.

The goal is to filter out common timestamps in all my 500 data frames and create a subset of new 500 data frames with just common timestamps.

Comment: How are your 500 DataFrames stored? Are they in some sort of list, or dictionary?

Comment: Hey, each data frame is being called by Pandas csv read.

Comment: You can use set logic `set(A) & set(B)` to find the common elements of `A` and `B`. Using `reduce` from `functools` you'd be able to get all of the common dates with something like: `reduce(lambda l,r: l & r, [set(pd.read_csv(file).Date) for file in [your_file_list]])`, then re-read all of the files and susbet to them to the dates found in that set. Or perhaps you can store everything in memory, so store them in a dict iniially:

Comment: Yes, all have exact common names. Thank you for your suggestion, will try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can store all 500 in memory at once, then it's useful to store them in a dictionary. Then you can find the intersection of all dates, and then save the subsets:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

d = dict((file, pd.read_csv(file)) for file in [your_list_of_files])

date_com = reduce(lambda l,r: l & r [set(df.Date) for _,df in d.items()])

for file,df in d.items():
    df[df.Date.isin(date_com)].to_csv(f'adjusted_{file}')
```